# What's the difference between `PT-Cloud` and `PT-Empty` in Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: networking, cloud, emulator

In the Cisco Packet Tracer:

[image]

There are two points I don't understand:

1. What's the meaning of `PT` of `PT-Cloud`?
2. What's the difference between `PT-Cloud` and `PT-Empty`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What's the meaning of PT of PT-Cloud?

IMO,  `PT` stands for `Packet Tracer`.

> 2. What's the difference between PT-Cloud and PT-Empty?

There are some pre-installed modules on `PT-Cloud`, but `PT-Empty` does not.

Modules on `PT-Cloud`:

- 2 x PT-CLOUD-NM-1AM
- 4 x PT-CLOUD-NM-1S
- 1 x PT-CLOUD-NM-1CX
- 1 x PT-CLOUD-NM-1CE

[image: Compare PT-Cloud and PT-Empty]

My Packet Tracer version is 7.2.1.0218.